# Docker: error during connect

Tags: docker, rselenium, docker-engine

I am getting the above error whenever i am trying to use RSelenium package

```
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome')
docker: error during connect: Post 
http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.30/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
See 'docker run --help'.
Warning messages:
1: running command 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c docker run -d -p 
4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome' had status 127 
2: In shell("docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome") :
  'docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome' execution failed with error code 127
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the stauts of docker environment variables which is not properly set. Kindly, check with the below command,

```
docker-machine env box
```

(Note: By default the env set for docker-machine is default)

Otherwise you can set it as like the below

```
$ set | grep DOCKER
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=C:\Users\mohan\.docker\machine\machines\deis
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://192.168.99.100:2376
DOCKER_MACHINE_NAME=deis
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1
DOCKER_TOOLBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox

$ docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM        DOCKER        ERRORS
deis   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376            v17.03.0-ce

$ docker ps -a
time="2017-03-23T11:11:55-07:00" level=info msg="Unable to use system  certificate pool: crypto/x509: system root pool is not available on Windows"
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES

$ docker pull busybox
time="2017-03-23T11:13:07-07:00" level=info msg="Unable to use system  certificate pool: crypto/x509: system root pool is not available on Windows"
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
7520415ce762: Pull complete
Digest:   sha256:32f093055929dbc23dec4d03e09dfe971f5973a9ca5cf059cbfb644c206aa83f
Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:latest
```

Hope this will work.