# Why Docker can't start or starting forever?

Tags: docker

I have installed docker on Windows 10, run it as administrator.
It's still in the process of launching (starting) after half an hour.
Log looks like:

```
    Version: 17.07.0-ce-win26 (13125)
    Channel: edge
    Sha1: 7c2cb3783c478f82e7a09cfbd5933d7b587c9c1e
    Started on: 2017/09/06 09:17:16.119
    Resources: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources
    OS: Windows 10 Pro
    Edition: Professional
    Id: 1607
    Build: 14393
    BuildLabName: 14393.1593.amd64fre.rs1_release.170731-1934
    ...


 [09:18:19.619][DockerDaemonChecker][Error  ] Docker daemon is not running
    [09:18:19.658][NamedPipeServer][Error  ] Unable to execute Start: error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.31/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
        в Docker.Backend.DockerDaemonChecker.Check(Func`1 isDaemonProcessStillRunning) в C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\DockerDaemonChecker.cs:line 63
       в Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.<Register>b__0(Object[] parameters) в C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line 47
       в Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeServer.RunAction(String action, Object[] parameters) в C:\gopath\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeServer.cs:line 145
    [09:18:19.674][NamedPipeClient][Error  ] Unable to send Start: error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.31/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.

    [09:18:19.674][Notifications  ][Error  ] error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.31/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.

    [09:18:19.705][CrashReport    ][Info   ] Preparing package to send with the diagnostics
```

I am trying to reboot, shut down PC, virtualization is enable in bios.
Could you give me some advise to solve the problem?

Comment: check this out, it may solve your problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856273/docker-error-during-connect/45856985#45856985

Comment: Maybe related: ["Docker Desktop Starting..." forever on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71238673/docker-desktop-starting-forever-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem some weeks ago with a new user of our systems.
In my case i forgot to add the user to the **docker-users** group.

Further problems/solutions that i already had:

1. not enough memory, docker consumes some of it
2. Crashed containers
3. Firewall or other tools that block even local TCP access
4. Bad docker config in %ProgramData%\Docker\config\daemon.json, you could for example try to set it to an empty json file ({})