# Error with using docker - error during connect

Tags: docker

I have installed docker in windows 10 OS, now I am just running some commands but getting errors. I am completed new to docker.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker run dockerinaction/hello_world
docker: error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect.: Post "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/containers/create": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Also getting error with version:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker version
error during connect: In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect.: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.24/version": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
Client:
 Cloud integration: 1.0.17
 Version:           20.10.7
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.4
 Git commit:        f0df350
 Built:             Wed Jun  2 12:00:56 2021
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true
```

I tried to run another command `docker-machine` after looking at the post [Docker cannot start on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459280/docker-cannot-start-on-windows)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker-machine env --shell cmd default
'docker-machine' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Also I tried another command after looking at post - [Docker: error during connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856273/docker-error-during-connect)

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>docker-machine env box
'docker-machine' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How to fix these errors?

Answer (score 0):

I would first start by running docker as elevated like the error says. Docker-machine isn't working because it's not on your PATH or whatever the windows equivalent is. I've not heard of docker machine and a quick check locally tells me that this isn't included as a part of the standard install so It may need to be installed separately

Here is the GitHub repo for docker machine but looking at it, it only really used for older Past
https://github.com/docker/machine/releases

Comment: `I would first start by running docker as elevated like the error says` What should I do for this?

Comment: right click and `Run as Administrator` for docker desktop